# How to Select and Load saved game snapshot from google play games

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am on the Saved Games screen where is shows the list of all saves. When I select a saved game the app crashes with the error: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataEntity

It's basically the same code from here https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames?authuser=3&hl=sl

Please assist.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_LIST_SAVED_GAMES:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (intent != null) {
                        if (intent.hasExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA)) {
                            // Error occurs here when saved game is selected
                            SnapshotMetadata snapshotMetadata = intent.getParcelableExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA);
                            assert snapshotMetadata != null;
                            sCurrentSaveName = snapshotMetadata.getUniqueName();
                            onLoadFromSnapshot(intent.getParcelableExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA));
                        } else if (intent.hasExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_NEW)) {
                            String unique = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            sCurrentSaveName = "snapshotH-" + unique;
                            onSaveSnapshot(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**This is what is shown in Logcat**

2020-02-07 19:07:07.410 31988-31988/com.positivelymade.homeless2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.positivelymade.homeless2, PID: 31988
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9005, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.positivelymade.homeless2/com.positivelymade.homeless2.MainActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataEntity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4605)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
     Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataEntity
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2855)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2781)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2684)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3053)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:288)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:232)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.containsKey(BaseBundle.java:504)
        at android.content.Intent.hasExtra(Intent.java:7923)
        at com.positivelymade.homeless2.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:222)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7759)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4598)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4647) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: I built a custom save game and load game system using Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is not working only in my release build since it is using pro guard. I solved it by adding pro guard configuration described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/support-play-games-services)